# Get the time from playing app in android TV

Tags: python, android, api

Is there a way to get the time from Andriod TV of the media that is being played. Like when netflix is playing an episode how long it is playing etc...
In Kodi this is available through an API is there something like this for Andriod TV?

I want to get this data to display it on a clock i made of nixie tubes.

Every point in the good direction is helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this for finding the current playback time

```
public long onTimeShiftGetCurrentPosition() {
  if (getTvPlayer() != null && currentProgram != null) {
    return getTvPlayer().getCurrentPosition() +
      currentProgram.getStartTimeUtcMillis();
  }
  return TvInputManager.TIME_SHIFT_INVALID_TIME;
}
```

I would recommend you to read more about it over [here](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/tif/time-shifting)

Comment: I think this is for live tv i am looking for something like when netflix is playing you get the current time etc..